# AdMob showing test interstitials in released application

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

I've added AdMob interstitials to my iOS application and they work fine on the simulator, showing test interstitials. However, upon the release of my application on the App Store I've realized that the interstitials are still showing test interstitials and not live/paid interstitial ads. Have I missed something here?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you forgot to remove your test ID from your AdMob request. Your request should look something like this:

```
// AdMob Interstitial Request
interstitial.adUnitID = myPublisherID; // Your publisher ID
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request]; // Creates the request
request.testDevices = @[ @"myTestID"]; // Your test ID
[interstitial loadRequest:request]; // Loads the request
```

Remove or comment out `request.testDevices = @[ @"myTestID"]` and submit an update for your application.

Comment: I had that removed already :/ Unsure what is happening and I've tried all sorts :/

Comment: @Prateek Have you removed the test id from your `- (void)interstitialDidDismissScreen:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial` when creating a new request after a user dismisses the initial interstitial? Have you tried to recreate the problem on a device that is not setup for development? If you add your AdMob code to your question I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I have since removed the Admob code and am experimenting with other companies; however, I followed the tutorial at https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/interstitial exactly. I didn't implement that method as I was using it repeatedly and it was working fine repeatedly